# Three.js — Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to add Orbit Controls to my scene without success. The code below keeps giving me an error `Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor`. I have tried different solutions I came across the web but, the error still persists. What am I doing wrong?

**Pseudocode**

- Add Orbit Controls
- Be able to use Orbit Controls in the scene

Thank you in advance.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/diegooriani/pen/VwYGpbX?editors=0010)

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/three.js"></script>
    <script src="https://82mou.github.io/threejs/js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

// var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
// renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
// document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

// CAMERA
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 320 / 240, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(250, 200, 250);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

// add controls for the camera
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);



var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 50);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFFFFFF } );
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( plane );

camera.position.z = 200;

var animate = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    controls.update();

  // plane.rotation.x += 0.01;
  // plane.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render( scene, camera );

};

animate();
```

Comment: It requires 2 arguments `var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)`

Comment: Thank you for your reply Blindman67. Still no success though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an issue in your codepen. When you import `OrbitControls` via ES6 imports, it's not necessary to use the `THREE` namespace. So when doing something like this:

```
import { OrbitControls } from "https://unpkg.com/three@0.112/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
```

you have to to create `OrbitControls` like so:

```
controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/68kzagry/1/

Comment: If installed via npm, the correct way to import `OrbitControls` is thus: `import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';`